# Indexing engine independent Spring Data annotations?

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-data-solr, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've just started experimenting with Spring Data Solr and i'm thinking about trying out Spring Data Elasticsearch as well. I've noticed that the two implementations uses distinct annotations for the same thing. For eg. @Field annotation is defined by both implementations on it's own, no common @Field annotation defined in Spring Data's core.

Is there any way to annotate a POJO universally which works across indexing engines so i can swap implementations the same way i can do this with JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. These frameworks are pretty new and not standardized.

You can use a byte code manipulation library like ASM, Javassist or BCEL (google for `java byte code manipulation library`) to read the classes, locate the annotations of one framework and then translate them into the annotations of the other.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to hear this.